# Site works slowly since official launch

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I am not sure if this only happened to me or if anyone else has the same problem, but after the official launch of Ask Different this website has become very slow for me. For example, while scrolling up and down, instead of a continuous loading of the page it is more like frame by frame. And when typing, the characters do not show up as fast as I type.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.6, and use firefox 3.6.10. Also, I have a macbook-pro 2010 13" with 4GB 1067MHz DDR3 RAM, and a 2.53 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo.

Comment: can you tell us your web browser and OS?

Comment: @jeff I update my laptop specification.

Comment: I have pretty similar specs to you but I have a slower processor and I have no issues.  I'm using Google Chrome though

Comment: @Griffo you are right I test with Chrome and it's work fine with chrome,I thibk this theme it's not compatible with firefox or only with firefox + some Add-ons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Lion" redesign removed a lot of the weirder CSS3 on this site; see if that helps!

Comment: ye it's become better, I don't have any of the previous problem, But I must add this that I upgrade my firefox to firefox 4 too, when I have problem with Ask Different I use firefox 3. Tanx anyway

Answer (score 0):

If it works OK in Chrome and not Firefox then it points at the browser probably unless this was a widespread issue but so far you seem to be the only person complaining.  I suppose there are a lot of variables but you could try disabling any addons in Firefox temporarily to see if that's the cause and if not then you could submit a bug report to the [Mozilla project](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro this. But I've had performance issues with Firefox sometimes, not just with our site. I believe FF has a memory issue, if I have many tabs open and leave them on for a while, all sites I visit become so slow.

Can you check how much memory FF is using in Activity Monitor when you experience performance issue? I've found that sometimes FF can take up gigs of memory. That's why for personal use I have switched to Chrome. I only use FF for development.

Comment: For testing what you said I restart my OS X and run firefox again and load askdifferent.com when firefox just get 172 MB of my 4GB Real RAM (have 2.6GB free RAM )and 73MB of my virtual RAM but I still have this problem with Ask Different, I also must said that I don't have any problem with other SE sites with firefox.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: I've had similar problems in the past with other websites and Firefox that no one else was able to reproduce.  Try running FF in safe mode (no extensions) and see if it still happens.

Comment: @cala I am too lazy for test this one :D

Comment: @Am1rr3za: it's actually pretty easy and painless... all you have to do is hold down option while you click the FF icon, then click continue in safe mode.  It will go back to normal mode the next time you run it.

Comment: @cala I know how to switch to safe mode but I rarely restart my laptop.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: you don't have to restart the laptop after using safe mode, you just restart firefox.

Comment: @cala oh sorry man I think you said book OS X in safe mode :(, I write the result after the test.

Comment: @cal I test in safe mode but I still have this problem :(

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: no problem, I had a feeling we were having a communication problem :)  Sorry it didn't work, worth a try though I guess.